# Enrich HTML Report generated with Ant?

Tags: java, html, ant, junit, jenkins

I got a Jenkins server set up to compile and test code for a company that I am an intern at.

It makes a really awesome HTML report now but it lacks one piece of information that seems would make it complete. That would be the output from `System.out.println()` that I do in my Test class.

Here is the target to make the reports from my ant `build.xml` file:

```
<target name="test-report-systemtest" depends="compile-omittedmanage-systemtest" description="Generate Test Results as HTML">
    <delete dir="${deploy}\html" />
    <delete dir="${deploy}\xml" />
    <mkdir dir="${deploy}\html" />
    <mkdir dir="${deploy}\xml" />
    <mkdir dir="${omittedmanage-systemtestbin}" />
    <taskdef name="junitreport" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator" />
    <coverage>
        <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="off" haltonerror="off" fork="yes">
            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${deploy}" filtertrace="on">
                <fileset dir="${omittedmanage-unittestbin}" includes="**/*Test*.class" />
            </batchtest>
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
            <formatter type="xml" usefile="true" />
            <classpath>
                <path refid="omittedManage.classpath" />
            </classpath>
        </junit>
    </coverage>
    <echo message="running JUnit Report" />
    <junitreport todir="${deploy}\xml">
        <fileset dir="${deploy}\xml">
            <include name="Test-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${deploy}\html" />
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

What I get is this:

[image: Example]

That is really good, but it would be really nice to have something written, like "Output" where it says "Type". Then I could fill that with some sort of message from my Java. Here is the test itself(It's Parameterized so it pulls a "True/False" and a String from another method to place in this test method and assert either true or false:

```
@Test
public void testValidationOfFICheckCipher()
{
    try {
        System.out.println("Checking validity of EAN Checksum: " + eanString);
        boolean expect = new Boolean(expected);
        boolean value = new Boolean(CheckSums.validateEAN13(eanString));
        assertEquals(expect, value);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        assertTrue((eanString.length() < 13) || (eanString.length() > 13));
    }

}
```

I really want to have this line: `"Checking validity of EAN Checksum: " + eanString` show up in my HTML report. But I can't really figure out how to accomplish that...anyone who knows?

Comment: This is a old question but did you find a way to make system-out and system-err visible?

Comment: @lolung I don't think so :/ But also even if I did back then, that doesn't mean it would work the same today.